# Program sinus, cosinus, arc cos and arc sin manually

Tags: c#, trigonometry, .net-micro-framework

I am using .net micro framework 4.1. There are no goniometric functions but I need to count distance between two points on Eatrh. Can anybody help me with this problem? I think that best solution is to program functions manually but I do not know how.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the mathematical definition of the sinus cosinus and tanges ? If remember correctly the exponential definition for the Sinus is 1/2i*(e^(i+x) - e^-(i+x) )

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to create your own implementation of trigonometric functions since they already exists in `Math` class available in the .NET Micro Framework versions 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 4.0, 4.1, and 4.2.

See for example [Math.Sin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh423506.aspx) method.

Comment: that is true but it takes only an int as a argument and when I need to calculate longitude and latitude I need a double or float.

Comment: @JanHolešínský You could interpolate between values returned from `Math.Sin` by splitting the latitude and longitude into integer and fractional parts.  Use the integer part (and the integer part + 1) to get the values of `Math.Sin` and then use the fractional part to interpolate between them.

Comment: Yeah that's true but I need to count sinus,cosinus and arcus cosinus as fast as possible. Do you think that interpolation is a good idea?

Comment: @JanHolešínský well, actually you have two possible ways. You can use either interpolation or search from precomputed values stored in hashtable. Second approach should be faster, but it takes additional space to store precomputed values and also you should somehow precompute it with desired tolerance (probably using full .NET framework and then store it somewhere in file and fill hashtable from file on startup of your application).

Comment: I have an idea to get the value thourgh Taylors polynom but I am not sure if it is accurate enough

Answer (score 1):

if you have an GHI Device, than you can use for NETMF 4.1 the GHIElectronics NETMF MathEx Library.

[GHI Doku](http://old.ghielectronics.com/downloads/man/Library_Documentation_v4.1/html/a425963a-a256-3ad3-acaa-0502eb566ff4.htm)